# Come tradurre 'to look forward'?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, translation

Ragazzi ho bisogno di un piccolo aiuto per una traduzione. 
Farò due domande, una generale che può tornare utile a più persone ed una più specifica

**DOMANDA 1 - Generale:**

Come si può tradurre in italiano '**To look forward**'?

**DOMANDA 2 - Specifica:**

Come tradurreste in italiano:  '**The organizers of the event are looking forward to meet you**'?

Grazie mille!

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Come livello zero, partirei da:

```
Non veder l'ora
```

e,

```
Gli organizzatori dell'evento sono impazienti di incontrare i partecipanti.
```

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: In un contesto più formale come potremmo dire? Gli organizzatori non vedono l'ora di incontrarvi? Forse semplicemente non si usa in italiano una frase del genere?

Comment: @johnnyfittizio "non vedono l'ora" è meno formale di "sono impazienti". In italiano si usano certamente entrambe le espressioni.